# Integration of "drift and volatility" model $dp_t = p_t\mu dt + p_t\sigma \epsilon \sqrt{dt}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Can integration by separation be used to solve the differential equation for drift and volatility?

$$dp_t = p_t\mu dt + p_t\sigma \epsilon \sqrt{dt}$$

$$dp_t = p_t\left (\mu dt + \sigma \epsilon \sqrt{dt}\right )$$

$$\frac{dp_t}{p_t} = \mu dt + \sigma \epsilon \sqrt{dt}$$

$$\int\frac{dp_t}{p_t} = \int\mu dt + \int\sigma \epsilon \sqrt{dt}$$

$$\int\frac{dp_t}{p_t} = \mu \int dt + \sigma \epsilon \int (dt)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

$$\ln{p_t} = \mu t + \sigma \epsilon t + C$$

$$p_t = Ce^{t(\mu + \sigma \epsilon)}$$

Comment: How did you integrate the square root of the differential $\mathrm d t$? Also, you forgot the constant of integration.

Comment: tbh, I used an intergral calculator, not sure that it's correct, however.

Comment: I think I'd like to see how the equation was derived in the first place -- I'm curious to see how $\sqrt {\mathrm dt}$ could have arisen.

Comment: The second term, $p_t \sigma \epsilon \sqrt{dt}$, is a Brownian motion model for volatility.

Comment: What's up with the square root? How does it appear?

Comment: I don't think it makes little sense because if we set $\sqrt{\mathrm dt}=\mathrm du,$ then we have that $\mathrm dt=\mathrm du^2,$ which is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do something like that with some justification relating to the Euler-Mayamura integration method. Start with a proper SDE using a Brownian motion process
$$
dp_t=p_tμdt+p_tσdW_t
$$
If the $dp_t=p(t+dt)-p(t)$ etc. is understood as discrete but very small updates you have on average $dW_t^2=dt$. Inserting you get
$$
p_{t+dt}=p_t(1+μdt+σdW_t).
$$
Note that the terms are not "properly" ordered, by size you have $1\gg dt\gg |dW_t|$.

If you carry out this recursion, you get a product of the factors $(1+μdt+σdW_t)$. The usual way to treat such a situation is to transform this into an exponential, $e^{\ln(1+μdt+σdW_t)}$ so that the product becomes effectively a sum. Expanding the logarithm gives
$$
\ln(1+μdt+σdW_t)=(μdt+σdW_t)-\frac12(μdt+σdW_t)^2+O(|dW_t|^3)
\\
=μdt+σdW_t-\frac12σ^2dW_t^2+O(|dW_t|^3)
$$
Now summing up these terms for $\sum_t dt = \Delta t$ is now simple and results in
$$
(\mu-\tfrac12σ^2)\Delta t + σ\Delta W_t + O(\Delta t\max_t|dW_t|)
$$
so that finally, in the limit $\max_t|dW_t|\to 0$, one gets
$$
p_{t+\Delta t}=p_te^{(\mu-\tfrac12σ^2)\Delta t + σ(W_{t+\Delta t} - W_t)}
$$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* OK, I think there's a way to make sense of $\sqrt {\mathrm dt}.$ Note that we have the general $k$ th differential of $t^n$ given by $$\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n-k+1)}t^{n-k}\mathrm dt^k.$$ This then gives $$\mathrm d^{1/2}t=\frac{\Gamma(2)}{\Gamma(1+1/2)}\mathrm dt=\frac{2}{\sqrt π}\mathrm dt.$$ Substituting this in your equation then gives you a separable equation, and you may proceed as usual.